# WordPress multi-site combined with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I will go in to the subject right after giving an example what this is about:
Maybe some of you are familiar with the Magento multi store solution. It let's you manage multiple stores (whether on the same domain using subdomains, or using different domains). Using multilpe stores, each store gets data from the same database. This makes it easy to control inventory in one central DB even when you sell the same article on multiple sites/stores.

WordPress released a multi-site possibility a while ago and WooCommerce can also be used in this setup. The problem here is that each site is an individual and new instance of a WordPress installation where you need to install themes, plugins and create a new products database from scratch. Because of this, there is no central products database and selling the same products over multiple stores gives problems with stock management. Also, I am not sure if you can use multi-site over multiple domains instead of only subdomains.

Do you guys have any experience with this or solving these problems?

Comment: You can do a cross-site query.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to reinstall themes and plugins for each site. Just activate across the network or activate on a site by site basis. The *point* of multisite is to share an installation. All the files are shared. The database is somewhat sharded, but they all live together so you can make cross site or global queries.

Multisite most definitely can be used with [multiple domains](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping). To make things easier you can use a plugin like [WPMU Dev's Domain Mapper](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/)

As for having a centralized store for all the sites. Looks like this plugin will do what you want: https://woomultistore.com/ (Or [this one](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-multisite-product-sync/20137238). Or [this](https://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/wordpress-multisite-plugin-woocommerce/))

---

Honestly this stuff isn't hard to find. Just research and experiment. You should find a good combination that will accomplish your goals pretty quickly. Maybe a little custom coding. If it doesn't exist, then make it! You can sell it on CodeCanyon or similar or just give it to the community as a repayment for all the free plugins they gave to you.